# Undefined property error in custom module

Tags: 7

I am getting errors on specific pages of my drupal site pointing specifically to this line..

```
if (is_object($argument) && in_array($router_item['page_arguments'][$key]->type, array('article', 'page'))) {
```

what could be the problem? Here's the complete error and function.

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$type in custommodule_menu_local_tasks_alter().

```
function custommodule_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $router_item, $root_path) {
  foreach ($router_item['page_arguments'] as $key => $argument) {
    if (is_object($argument) && in_array($router_item['page_arguments'][$key]->type, array('article', 'page'))) {
      foreach ($data['tabs'][0]['output'] as $key => $value) {
        if (($value['#link']['path'] == 'node/%/edit'||'node/%/view') && (!user_access('administer nodes'))){
          unset($data['tabs'][0]['output'][$key]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit:
There are similar error in following line..

```
foreach ($data['tabs'][0]['output'] as $key => $value) {
```

--Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in custommodule_menu_local_tasks_alter() (line 59 of...)
--Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in custommodule_menu_local_tasks_alter() (line 59 of ...).

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! How to fix a "Undefined property" error is a plain PHP question, since `isset()` is just PHP. There is nothing different in Drupal; in fact, Drupal uses `isset()` often in its code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely  **$router_item['page_arguments'][$key]->type** is undefined.

Try with :

```
if (is_object($argument) && isset($router_item['page_arguments'][$key]->type) && in_array($router_item['page_arguments'][$key]->type, array('article', 'page'))) {
```

Same thing for that foreach loop. Just add an if isset() before that loop and you'll be ok.

```
if (isset($data['tabs'][0]['output']) ) {
    foreach ($data['tabs'][0]['output'] as $key => $value) {
        ....
```

Comment: Thanks, that did remove the "undefined property error" but there are more errors, will edit and add info in my question

Comment: Same thing for that undefined offset. Basically whenever you use arrays or objects you have to make sure that they the array entries or object properties that you refer to do actually exist. Or else php will error. So when in doubt just do an **if (isset( ... ))** on whatever you're using.